# X61T touchscreen causing freezing under Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: thinkpad, tablet, touchscreen, wacom

Recently my SO got herself a X61 Tablet. It's really great, except for one problem - the touchscreen doesn't work under Xubuntu 16.04. Whenever I touch the screen with the stylus, it works for a split second, the mouse moves and then it freezes the whole system - the only thing left to do is to reset. The WACOM tablet is recognized as an input device, so no problem there.
I have tried booting with different kernels and in safe mode, but no luck - it's exactly the same problem every time.
I have also tried removing **inputattach** as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166028) and still the same thing.

I have scourged the net looking for a solution, but nobody else seems to have this problem. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well. It seems that on Linux 4.2.0 there is no freeze, but 4.4.0 there is a freeze. Try downgrading your kernel (press Esc at Grub, go to advanced options and pick an older one.) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that upgrading the kernel to 4.8.0 did the trick. Thanks.